# Unable to get value of element that is a passed through props

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an app that will add items to an array that is displayed on the homepage.
It displays items based off of their value, and I am trying to create buttons that highlight when their value is in the array.

I have a button component here

```
const ButtonClickable = (props) => {
    const [isActive, setActive] = useState("false");
    const handleToggle = () => {
     setActive(!isActive);
    }; 
     return <button
               type="button"
               value={props.value}
               className={isActive ? "button btn first" : "button btn firstActive"}
               onClick={handleToggle}
             >
              {props.name}
             </button>
   
   }
```

And I am using it like this

```
 <ButtonClickable onClick={(event) => {ToppingPlusMinus(event)}}  name="Cheese" value="Cheese, " ></ButtonClickable>
```

And I am gathering the value with the following functions

```
const ToppingPlusMinus = (e) => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  const position = toppings.indexOf(value);

  if (position !== -1) {
    return removeTopping(value);
    
  }

  return addTopping(value);
  
};


const removeTopping = (value) => {
  // We need to filter out the value from the array and return the expected new value
  setToppings(toppings.filter((topping) => topping !== value));
  handleToggle();
};
```

These functions work just fine when the value is hardcoded in the same component like so:

```
<button
            type="button"
            value="Peperoni, "
            className={ isActive ? "button btn first" : "button btn firstActive"} 
            onClick={(event) => {
              ToppingPlusMinus(event);
            }}
          >
            Pepperoni
          </button>
```

When I use the `<buttonClickable>` Component the value does not add to the array, and I am not sure why.

 A full working code sandbox is [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-breeze-whui6?file=/src/CYO.js)
I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Because in `buttonClickable` you are only toggling `isActive` and not calling the `onClick` prop that is passed in.

Comment: I had that thought too. I was using this line below the ```isActive``` ```props.onClick && props.onClick(props.value)``` However when this line is there the entire app crashes with a message of ```Cannot destructure property 'value' of 'e.target' as it is undefined.```

Comment: Check my answer see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the onClick prop that you passed in, change your click handler like this:

```
const handleToggle = (e) => {
     props.onClick(e)
     setActive(!isActive);
 };
```

Comment: In your ButtonClickable

Comment: Thank you, (i figured out my followup question)